# Cannot get the number from def function in python by using local variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a python code to check if chaddar equal 1 and 'yes' in horn. However I cannot get the chaddar number from def sth(chaddar) and my code always print error. I cannot use golbal variable I can only use local variable.So I really need some help. Thanks

Here is my code:

```
def sth(chaddar):
  chaddar = 1 
def basic(chaddar):
  horn = input("answer: ")
  if chaddar ==1 and "yes" in horn:
    print("ok")
  else:
    print("error")
sth('chaddar')
basic('chaddar')
```

My Terminal:

```
answer: yes
 error
```

Comment: Try calling `basic(1)`.

Comment: or you can do.. `chaddar = sth('chaddar')` #nextline-> `basic(chaddar)`

Answer (score 0):

This is all looking pretty crazy, but this should do it:

```
def basic(chaddar):
  horn = input("answer: ")
  if chaddar ==1 and "yes" in horn:
    print("ok")
  else:
    print("error")

basic(1)
```

#### Problems

- The `sth` function is irrelevant
- You were sending a string to `basic` but testing the value against `1`.

Answer (score 0):

`sth("chaddar")` doesn't set the local variable `chaddar` in `basic()` to 1; it only sets `chaddar` to be 1 in `sth()`.

If you want to achieve this, then you would need to do:

```py
def sth(chaddar):
  global chaddar
  chaddar = 1

def basic(chaddar):
  horn = input("answer: ")
  if chaddar == 1 and "yes" in horn:
    print("ok")
  else:
    print("error")

chaddar = "chaddar"
sth(chaddar)
basic(chaddar)
```

But this would violate your 'no globals' principal.

Or something like:

```py
def sth(chaddarPath):
  with open(chaddarPath, "w") as chaddar:
  chaddar = 1 

def basic(chaddarPath):
  chaddarFile = open(chaddarPath, "r")
  chaddar = int(chaddarFile.read())
  chaddarFile.close()

  horn = input("answer: ")
  
  if chaddar == 1 and "yes" in horn:
    print("ok")
  else:
    print("error")

sth("chaddar.txt")
basic("chaddar.txt")
```

But this would be clunky and not very efficient.